# How to call Async method from non-Async method with method hook?

Tags: asynchronous, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

Scenario:
1. I'll get call from UI to my Web Api.
2. My business logic process some data and create two lists.
3. Out of these two list one list data has to be return to the UI back and remaining list data again processed by another component which returns me the result on which i again has some business logic to be executed.

What will be the best practices and how will it be implemented?
Please provide the code snippets.

Comment: First, *you* should provide your code. What async method? What non-async method? What do you mean by `method hook`? C# doesn't have nay method hooks. How can anyone help when you don't give any information?

Comment: Besides, if you have `async` methods, why don't you use `async` ?

Comment: @Panagiotis  :- i think there is no need to provide any code. because it is a fresh implementation in which i do not write any code yet.and the detail scenario i mentioned in my question, i think it is  self explanatory what i want to accomplish. secondly i accept that title i put method hooks is confusing. for hooks i mean to say when call back of async method will come i need a function which will be executed. As per my assumption if you know c# doesn't have any method hooks, you also know there is concept in c# Async methods,parallel execution ,TASKS etc. hw to use them to solve my problem